# Is there a way to activate a button press in unity XR using the interactor events

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, events, virtual-reality

Is there a way to activate a button press in unity xr using the interactor events, without pressing the controller button

Comment: So far, I am only able to get the ray interactor to click when I press the trigger button, but I want it to click when I hover over the button.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add a pointer enter event on the button to make it work. Unity buttons comes with onclick event by default, so this needed to be changed